# Issues reading sdcard on GD32, using IAR EWARM on c

Tags: c, gcc, arm, iar

We are using A GD32F1 to run an application on IAR EWARM which is collecting data of uint32_t [2][2][ARR_SIZE], and storing it on an SD card.

The ARR_SIZE was initially declared as 1500, and the code ran well on the board. However, we found that the size allocated would not be sufficient for all edge cases, so we increased the ARR_SIZE to 2000. On flashing the code to the board, and debugging the code would get stuck in a hard fault, and on closer examination the code was looping around on [line 509](https://github.com/a-v-s/GD32F10x_Firmware_Library/blob/1a883ee77c94ecbe7fb73e8f741a1364cc3bf7f0/Examples/SDIO/Read_write/sdcard.c#L509). The program is constantly iterating inside the while loop, without entering the subsequent if block.

We tried reducing the ARR_SIZE and we found that 1800 works okay. We've also tried the same code with even higher sizes of ARR_SIZE (3000) on arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler and that seemed to work fine too.

I'd like to understand why the code is behaving differently on the two compilers.

Also, worth noting the IAR binary is around 39kB whereas the gcc binary is 69kB.

Comment: Is your array allocated on stack?

Comment: @user694733 I'm not sure. How can I check this?

Comment: Is your array allocated inside or outside of function? How is it allocated? If array is allocated in stack, and your stack is too small, then you can get stack overflow.

Comment: Okay, so the array is allocated outside of the function.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your system? With 1500 entries your array takes 24kiB. With 2000 it takes 32kiB.

Comment: We're using [this](https://www.gigadevice.com/microcontroller/gd32f103vgt6/). It's got 96kB of RAM

Comment: If array is allocated outside of function, then it should have static storage duration and should be visible in your linker map (map file generation can be enabled in IAR linker settings). Check map file to see that array is correct size and in correct place, and what addresses it occupies. Then check in debugger that you are actually within those memory addresses when writing into the array. If you have wrong pointer access for example, you may write outside of the array bounds by accident.